# loading records from mnesia dump is not writing to disk

Tags: erlang, mnesia

Before I got started on this project I determined that my DB had been corrupted such that all new records were being inserted as ram_copies instead of disc_copies.

So I took a backup:

`mnesia:dump_to_textfile("fixerupper99.txt").`

I went through the text file and added the disc_copies atribute to the table list section of the text file.

At this point I stopped my app and all of the extra nodes. I also deleted all of the files in the mnesia dir.

`rm DECISION_TAB.LOG LATEST.LOG schema.DAT *.DC[DL]`

It generated a nice file that had everything in it. Schema and records. After experimenting I realized that it was missing the `create table` attributes for persisting to disk `{disc_copies, [metagate@KS0002]}`.

The steps I followed:

- mnesia:stop().
- mnesia:create_schema([nodes()]).
- mnesia:start().
- mnesia:info().

At this point everything looked ok., but empty. Next I began loading in the data from the dump-file. `mnesia:load_textfile("fixerupper99.txt").`

I immediately checked the info `mnesia:info().` and everything was as I expected. I then exited `erl` and went to look at the folder where I was storing the mnesia data. All of the files that I expected to have disc_copies existed in the folder but all of the files were practically empty.

Well, no matter what I do it seems that the files/tables are still being considered as ram_copies and so they are not being written to disk.

I tried `change_table_copy_type()` but that did not work correctly.

Mnesia:info says that my files are on disk but a restart of the application causes all of the data to disappear. ideas?

Comment: Can you explain what happened when you tried calling `mnesia:change_table_copy_type/3`? Did you get an error? Or did it simply not change the output of `mnesia:info/0`?

Comment: Also, can you more information about the nodes in your Mnesia cluster? Are they all on one machine? Are they all connected properly? Can you ping them all?

Comment: Perhaps this is relevant? http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2012-August/068692.html

Answer (score 0):

The proper method of changing a table copy type is to do the following:

```
% Assume we have a list of all the nodes in the mnesia cluster 
% (I assume you have more than one node)
Nodes = [node1, node2],
Table = some_table_name,

% You probably want to make the copy type change on all nodes
% (again, assuming you have more than one node)
lists:foreach(fun(Node) ->
  {atomic, ok} = mnesia:change_table_copy_type(Table, Node, disc_copies),
end, Nodes).
```

After running this change `mnesia:info/0` should show the updated tables, with the correct copy type:

```
mnesia:info().
```

**Update**

Corrected `disk_copies` to `disc_copies`.

Comment: disc_copies not disk_copies

Comment: Are you saying that adding the {disc_copies, [metagate@KS0002]} to the schema section of the loadfile is not going to work? Through my experimentation, including, deleting all of the DCD, DCL, LOG and schema files I was able to get load_textfile() to set the tables as disc_copies. In a few tests I tried change_table_copy_type and while it changed the type in the mnesia:info() (1) writes to the tables were never written to disk (2) the record count never advanced. Can you reference the documentation that suggests this is the best course? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if changing the schema section of the schema file will work or not. I don't think making manual changes to the files in the Mnesia is documented anywhere. The mnesia modules API is well documented and should be preferred over other methods. I am not saying it won't work, just that as far as I know, that method of changing the table copy type is undocumented. Not sure if you have seen this or not, but it does talk a little about `change_table_copy_type`: http://erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_chap5.html

Comment: the documentation does talk about the file format of the textfile, in addition to being for educational purposes only.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was isolated when I realized that two nodes on the same system were using the same Mnesia dir. As a result there was likely a race condition between the nodes essentially preventing anything rational from happening.